# Upload CSV file Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am using the file_picker plugin to pick a CSV file in Flutter Web. Although I am able to pick the file it is converting the file into bytes (Uint8List). Is there any way I can get the original CSV file or if I can convert these bytes to CSV maybe I can get the path of the file?

Code:

```
 void pickCSV() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['csv']);
    if (result != null) {
      var fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
      csfFileName.value = result.files.first.name;
    } else {
      // User canceled the picker
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/exploring-csv-in-flutter-fafc57b02eb1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843717/flutter-upload-csv-file

Comment: @AnmolMishra this is for mobile, my question is for flutter web

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but you have a couple of choices and maybe it helps others out aswell.

Both of the choices requires server-side processing, so you will need to read on how to do that.

1. Get the content of the CSV file send it to the server and make a new file on the server with that content. You can use [String.fromCharCodes](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCodes.html) to read the content, in the web, after you select the file.
2. Convert the Uint8List into a base64 string, using [base64Encode](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-convert/base64Encode.html) function, send it to the server, process it there.

Alternatively, if you use Firebase Storage you can use [putData](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/upload-files/#uploading-raw-data) like so:

```
final metaData = SettableMetadata(contentType: mimeType);
final task = await _storage.ref().child(cloudPath).putData(fileData, metaData);
/// Get the URL
await task.ref.getDownloadURL()
```

- Storing the mimeType ensures proper handling of the file when used after download
- cloudPath means the location in FirebaseStorage, such as: storageDirectory/filename.extension
- fileData is the Uint8List you provided